# How to create Google API as an agency?

Tags: google-oauth, gmail-api, google-developers-console

Hi I looked https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key

For an agency, is it possible to set up an API without having the client's login?

How can we create one?

Regards,

Jeff

Answer (score 0):

Api keys are for accessing public data there will be no need for logging in when you use this.

Use the follow these steps to get an API key:

- Go to the [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=places_backend&reusekey=true).
- Create or select a project.
- Click Continue to enable the API.
- On the Credentials page, get an API key (and set the API key restrictions).
  Note: If you have an existing unrestricted API key, or a key with server restrictions, you may use that key.
- To prevent quota theft, [secure your API key following these best practices](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6310037).
  (Optional) Enable billing. See [Usage Limits and Billing](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage) for more information.

There is no other way to get an API key you will need to create a project on google developer console.